# MySQL lookup performance PK unsigned INT vs indexed varchar(15) column

Tags: mysql, database, performance

Would there be a significant performance difference between looking up a MySQL table (currently 2M rows) using PK unsigned int(4 bytes) vs varchar(15) (unique index) column?

Comment: Related: [Find out MySQL index size for a concrete index](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12354/find-out-mysql-index-size-for-a-concrete-index/14681)

Comment: 15 characters in utf8 are 60 bytes - I'd be brave and say w/o thinking further it'd be at least 15 times slower

Answer (score 0):

The problem with VARCHAR being used for any KEY is that they can hold WHITE SPACE. White space consists of ANY non-screen-readable character, like spaces tabs, carriage returns etc. Using a VARCHAR as a key can make your life difficult when you start to hunt down why tables aren't returning records with extra spaces at the end of their keys.

Sure, you CAN use VARCHAR, but you do have to be very careful with the input and output. They also take up more space and are likely slower when doing a Queries.

Integer types have a small list of 10 characters that are valid, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. They are a much better solution to use as keys.

You could always use an integer-based key and use VARCHAR as a UNIQUE value if you wanted to have the advantages of faster lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter keys means more keys per index block, means fewer index block retrievals, means faster lookups.

Comment: Thanks, do you know roughly what the difference can be? Please note varchar index is unique.